# Numpy linalg: linear system with unlikely results

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, equation

Considering the following matrix equation:

```
x=Ab
```

where:

```
In[1]:A
Out[1]:
matrix([[ 0.477, -0.277, -0.2  ],
        [-0.277,  0.444, -0.167],
        [-0.2  , -0.167,  0.367]])

In[2]: b
Out[2]: [0, 60, 40]
```

how come that when I use `numpy.linalg()` I get the following results?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
res=x.tolist()
# res=[1.8014398509481981e+18, 1.801439850948198e+18, 1.8014398509481984e+18]
```

These numbers are huge! What's wrong here? I am suspecting `A` is in the wrong form, as it multiplies `b` in my equation, whereas `numpy.linalg()` considers `A` as if it multiplies `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you give as an equation (`x=A b`) is just a [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) rather than a set of linear equations to solve (`A x=b`) for which you would use [`np.linalg.solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html). What you need to do to get `x` in your case is simply use [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) (`A.dot(b)`).

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is singular, as can be seen by adding its columns which sum to zero. Mathematically, this system is only solvable for a very small set of `b` vectors.

The solution you're getting is most likely just numerical noise.